# Hide home bar flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I tried to hide the home indicator for Android but nothing worked for me
1)
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);

2. safe area also not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);` to this `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` and your app should hide your home bar.